# How to use assembly version as project version in SonarQube?

Tags: .net, sonarqube

In `SonarQube` for `.NET` you need to provide the `/version:` attribute to the `MSBuild Runner`. Is it possible to replace the `/version:` attribute with e.g. a Version (or part of a version) from a (built) assembly?

It would be easier than remembering to change the `SonarQube` build every time the version changes.

Ideally it would take the version from a specific assembly (after it being built), because we are also applying custom versioning to it during the build.

Comment: Have you found any solution for that issue ? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing right now. Thanks.

Comment: @mberube.NET I haven't tried this further. I think the best way would be to let the build system calculate the version number, then set it on SQ and the assemblyinfo.cs so they match.